# Find the value in the middle of the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm

Greeting everyone! I need help, i have the list with an odd numbers of elements, and i have to find the value placed in the middle of the list. I mean, i have the list: [1, 4, 5, 6, 7]
The middle value is 5 because it placed between 2 numbers left and 2 numbers right. So how to find this value with python?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you try taking a shower and some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you first get the length of your list `len(listName)` you can store it in a new variable. The element in the middle of the list is the element at the index `length // 2` because the first element of the list have an index of 0
so the element will be:
`array[len(array) // 2]`

Answer (score 0):

To find a middle number, just use array.length/2
but if array.length is even, you may need to find two.
The way to find a middle number is different from problem to problem.
So you should read Question well.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
l = [1,2,3]

l[len(l)//2]
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the Low Quality Queue. Here are some guidelines for How do I write a good answer?. Code only answers are not considered good answers, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are less useful to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / better than existing answers.